# GO script runtime error for Amazon AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, go, amazon-s3, runtime-error

I'm currently attempting to run the following Golang build for the first time on a Amazon Linux Distro:

https://github.com/adammck/s3-graphite

README Here:

```
go get github.com/adammck/s3-graphite
cd $GOPATH/adammck/s3-graphite
go build
```

After this, I set my variables in my .bashrc file like below:

```
# AWS keys with read access to the bucket
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxxxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyyyyyyyyy
export AWS_REGION=us-east-1

# the bucket to watch
export S3_BUCKET=my-bucket
export S3_PREFIX=dir/subdir

# the server to send metrics to
export GRAPHITE_ADDRESS=metrics.example.com
export GRAPHITE_PREFIX=s3-count.my-bucket.dir.subdir
```

I set my GOPATH to the following:

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/work/"
```

I cd into the dir to run a go build which works like it should, but when I go to run the following after the go build:

./s3-graphite

I get the following error:

```
INFO[0000] Starting s3-graphite...
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x4e3256]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3.New(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3f)
    /home/ec2-user/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/service.go:41 +0x76
main.NewS3(0x7ffc202bef6e, 0x1b, 0x7ffc202be684, 0x9, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/ec2-user/work/src/github.com/adammck/s3-graphite/s3.go:20 +0x66
main.main()
    /home/ec2-user/work/src/github.com/adammck/s3-graphite/main.go:19 +0x21c

goroutine 2 [runnable]:
runtime.forcegchelper()
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/proc.go:90
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 3 [runnable]:
runtime.bgsweep()
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/mgc0.go:82
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 4 [runnable]:
runtime.runfinq()
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/malloc.go:712
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1
```

Here is my GOPATH:

```
$GOPATH
-bash: /home/ec2-user/work/: Is a directory
```

Here is my dir where I execute the s3-graphite:

```
/home/ec2-user/work/src/github.com/adammck/s3-graphite
```

EDIT (updated with items from your answer:

```
[ec2-user@s3-graphite]$ go version
go version go1.6.3 linux/amd64
[ec2-user@ s3-graphite]$ $GOPATH
-bash: /home/ec2-user/work: Is a directory
[ec2-user@ s3-graphite]$ pwd
/home/ec2-user/work/src/github.com/adammck/s3-graphite
[ec2-user@ s3-graphite]$ ./s3-graphite
INFO[0000] Starting s3-graphite...
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x512aa2]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x873120, 0xc82000a0e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3.New(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3f)
    /home/ec2-user/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/service.go:41 +0x72
main.NewS3(0xc82001603a, 0x1b, 0xc82000e06a, 0x9, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/ec2-user/work/src/github.com/adammck/s3-graphite/s3.go:20 +0x4a
main.main()
    /home/ec2-user/work/src/github.com/adammck/s3-graphite/main.go:19 +0x229
[ec2-user@ s3-graphite]$
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few things going on here. One thing to check is that you are actually sourcing your .bashrc file after you set the environment variables in there. You should be able to run the `env` command and see your AWS keys, S3 configuration, and graphite settings in your current shell.

The second problem I see is that the library you are using hasn't been updated since last year. As far as I know the AWS SDK for Go has changed a lot in the past year. The "panic:" line in your application's output gives a hint at the problem.

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

It seems like `nil` is being passed somewhere it is not supposed to be. Further down the panic output you can see the stacktrace for goroutine 1 says:

```
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3.New(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3f)
    /home/ec2-user/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/service.go:41 +0x76
main.NewS3(0x7ffc202bef6e, 0x1b, 0x7ffc202be684, 0x9, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/ec2-user/work/src/github.com/adammck/s3-graphite/s3.go:20 +0x66
```

From this you can see that the NewS3 method is being called on line 20 of the s3.go file in the s3-graphite library. Then it goes to the aws-sdk-go library and tries to create a new S3 client. With the following arguments:

> s3.New(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3f)

My best guy is that your configuration is not exported to the environment you are running the executable in, or the s3-graphite library needs to be updated to work with the latest aws-sdk-go version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I updated the GO Version and made sure to get the $GOPATH working along with sourcing the .bashrc file with the data I need, but it's still a no go.  Please see edit above in main post. @rking788